# Sitecore 7.2 - creating custome save to database action

Tags: sitecore, customization

I'm trying to create custom save to database action in Sitecore 7.2. I found one post on how do achieve this but couldn't find required DLL anywhere.

I need DLL - "Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions" to create a custom save to database action.

Can anyone please advise how to get this DLL? Do I need to download wffm module from somewhere or it comes with Sitecore ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use WFFM module? Or write something that is not related in any way to this module? Can you describe a bit more what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download the WFFM packages on the sitecore website unzip it twice and the you will have a folder nammed "files\bin" your dll will be in this folder.